# custom spring xd module with spring data elasticsearch: No qualifying bean of type [ElasticsearchTemplate] found

Tags: spring-xd

I customed a spring xd processor module,try link to elasticsearch in my module with spring data elasticsearch.
unittest is ok,but when deploy in the singlenode, throw the exception:

```html
 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.
config.TransformerFactoryBean#0': Cannot create inner bean 'com.eheluo.bigdata.wenxin.ToElasticsearch#0' of type [com.eh
eluo.bigdata.wenxin.ToElasticsearch] while setting bean property 'targetObject'; nested exception is org.springframework
.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.eheluo.bigdata.wenxin.ToElasticsearch#0': Injec
tion of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Coul
d not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate com.eheluo.bigdata.wenxi
n.ToElasticsearch.elasticsearchTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionExcep
tion: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate] found for dependenc
y: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.spr
ingframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

it can't find bean org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.

**my pom file is:**

```html
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.xd</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-xd-module-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath></relativePath>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
....
```

**my custom module code is :**

```html
@Component
public class ToElasticsearch {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ToElasticsearch.class);

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

    public String process(NewDataInterface data){
        NewData newData = new NewData();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(data, newData);

        String docid = elasticsearchTemplate.index(genIndexQuery(newData));
        logger.debug("save to es");
        return docid;
    }
```

**my application.properties is :**

```html
# options_class=com.eheluo.bigdata.wenxin.ToElasticsearch
# ELASTICSEARCH (ElasticsearchProperties})
# The cluster name (defaults to elasticsearch)
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=elasticsearch
# The address(es) of the server node (comma-separated; if not specified starts a client node)
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=127.0.0.1:9300
 # if spring data repository support is enabled
spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true
```

my module.properties has nothing to export options
my module.xml is :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch-1.0.xsd
 ">

    <channel id="input"/>

    <transformer input-channel="input" output-channel="output">
        <beans:bean class="com.eheluo.bigdata.wenxin.ToElasticsearch" />
    </transformer>

    <channel id="output"/>

</beans:beans>
```

my unittest is :

```html
public class ToElasticsearchTest {
    private static SingleNodeApplication application;

    private static int RECEIVE_TIMEOUT = 5000;

    private static String moduleName = "toelasticsearch";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        RandomConfigurationSupport randomConfigSupport = new RandomConfigurationSupport();
        application = new SingleNodeApplication().run();
        SingleNodeIntegrationTestSupport singleNodeIntegrationTestSupport = new SingleNodeIntegrationTestSupport(application);
        singleNodeIntegrationTestSupport.addModuleRegistry(new SingletonModuleRegistry(ModuleType.processor, moduleName));
    }

  
    @Test
    public void test() {
        String streamName = "toElasticsearchTest";


        String newID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        NewDataInterface newData = new NewDataPOJO();
        newData.setsomthing("testtesttest");
        newData.setId(newID);

        Multiset<String> words = ConcurrentHashMultiset.create();
        words.add("1");
        words.add("2");
        words.add("3");
        words.add("4", 2);
        newData.setsomthinx(words);



        String processingChainUnderTest = moduleName;

        SingleNodeProcessingChain chain = chain(application, streamName, processingChainUnderTest);

        chain.sendPayload(newData);

        String result = (String) chain.receivePayload(RECEIVE_TIMEOUT);

        assertEquals(newID, result);
        chain.destroy();
    }

}
```

unit test is always ok:Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

but can't work in singlenode rutime.

why it can't find ElasticsearchTemplate in runtime?

Comment: when I copy spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch.jar, spring-data-elastticsearch.jar and elasticsearch relation jar to xd/lib directory ，it seems work.   but is there any way , do not need do that ?

Comment: When you build the module jar, do you see the dependent jars in the /lib folder? e.g. 

jar -tvf target/<module-jar>.jar | grep lib

Comment: i use `mvn clean package`  command to package my module, dependent jar which xd not have are in my module/lib in module-jar。

Comment: it seems that module application context do not load jars in  module/lib（even which are spring boot relation jar：spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch.jar, spring-data-elastticsearch.jar ） when xd load module。  but if copy them to xd/lib ， module can be correctly loaded。

Comment: in fact，i remove these denpendent lib from module/lib to xd/lib